# Sitecore: Efficient way to display the name of Item which is saved in field with type Link Types:Droptree

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sitecore, sitecore7.2

Let's says if Sitecore Item `item`has a field `Created by` with type `Link Types:Droptree`

I want to print the name of item which is saved in the field `Created by`. The following line  `<sc:Text Field="Created by" runat="server"/>` will print the **ItemId**. What is the efficient way to display the name of this item.

I know that I can get the item from the database and then print its name as:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblItemName"></asp:Label>
```

**In Codebehind:**

```
 if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                Item currentItem = Sitecore.Context.Item;

                Item relatedItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(currentItem["Created by"]);

                lblItemName.Text = relatedItem.Name;
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to render the name of an item with `<sc:Text />` as it is a **field** renderer.

So you will have to do like you did:

```
var currentItem = Sitecore.Context.Item;

// Alternative way to get the linked item
var createdByField = (ReferenceField) currentItem.Fields["Created by"];
var createdByItem = createdByField.TargetItem;
var createdByItemName = createdByItem.Name;

lblItemName.Text = createdByItemName;
```

If you want to render a **field** from the linked item (`createdByItem`) instead of the current context item, you can do it like this:

```
<sc:Text runat="server" Field="Headline" ID="scRelatedItem" />
```

and int the code behind you set the **Item** property to the item you want to read the **Headline** field from:

```
scRelatedItem.Item = createdByItem;
```

Doing it this way will also make the field editable by editors through the Page Editor (called Experience Editor in Sitecore 8).

Answer (score 1):

You would need to pass an Item value in to your `<sc:Text/>` tag or it will use the context item.

```
<sc:Text Field="Created by" Item="<%# RelatedItem %>" runat="server"/>
```

Set the value of `RelatedItem` in your code behind and call `DataBind();` at the end of your `Page_Load()` method